# display byte array as an Image swift ui

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a byteArray something like this, which is a server response image file

```
[-1, -40, -1, -31, 10, -74, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, -96, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, -72, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, -98, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, -90, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -80, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, +1,928,998 more]
```

this is working in kotlin, however, I want to display the image on ios but I do not know how
I have this in the common code

```
suspend fun fetchCustomerFile(): BenoResult<ByteArray>
```

Comment: ```let data = Data(your_array)
let img = UIImage(data: data)
``` try this

Comment: @udi Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'KotlinByteArray' conform to 'Sequence'

Answer (score 1):

Your array type is Int8 so first convert it with UInt8

```
let value1: [Int8] = [-1, -40, -1, -31, 10, -74, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, -96, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, -72, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, -98, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, -90, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -80, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, +1, ...]
    
let valueToUInt = value1.map(UInt8.init) // type of valueToUInt is [UInt8]
```

Then

```
 imageView.image = UIImage(data: Data(valueToUInt))
```

> According to comment:

Your array might be Int16,32,64 . There is no information about it . If its one of them use :

```
 let value1: [Int16] = [-1, -40, -1, -31, 10, -74, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, -96, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, -72, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, -98, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, -90, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -80, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, +1]
    
 let valueToUInt = value1.map(UInt16.init)
    
 image.image = UIImage(data: Data(bytes: valueToUInt, count: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size))
```

> Below is just for Int16 , if its 32 or 64 change 16s to 32 or 64 ..

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Not enough bits to represent the passed value

Comment: thank you Omar UIImage(data: Data(bytes: valueToUInt, count: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)) give me nil

Comment: So the problem might be in your byte array